# When log into standard account of PC run VBS that requires admin privs

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, vbscript

I need when I log into Windows account of standard user, VBS file should be run automatically.

I know I can create a new string value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` with data like

```
wscript.exe D:\my-script.vbs
```

But the operation that should be run in VBS file when I log into user account requires admin privs

How to resolve the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Windows Task Scheduler, you could create a task that runs at login of every user, with elevated privileges.

- As admin, open the taskscheduler `taskschd.msc`
- From the *Action* menu, select *Create Task*
- On the *General* tab, select the user account that will run your task. This can be a normal user, or a system account such as SYSTEM or NETWORK. If you need elevated privileges, check *Run with highest privileges*

[image: Task - general]

- On the *Triggers* tab, click *New*, set *Begin the task* to *At log on*, and Settings to *Any user*

[image: New trigger]

Answer (score 0):

Just click on <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run Box and type `shell:Common Startup` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

A special folder will be open for you.

Copy your vbscript inside it ! and Voila !

---

***EDIT:***

You can add this sub at the beginning of your vbscript in order to be run as Admin rights, and If UAC is enabled on the computer, something like this should work.

---

```
Call RunAsAdmin
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub RunAsAdmin()
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
        , chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & chr(34) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' You actual code goes here
Msgbox "If UAC is enabled on the computer, something like this should work",vbinformation+vbSystemModal,"Test"
```

---

You can create a shortcut on the startup user folder and execute your action with admin privileges like this vbscript :

---

```
Const Title = "Create a shortcut on startup user folder for the current vbscript that can be executed with Admin privileges"
Call RunAsAdmin()
Create_Shortcut Array("Startup","MyvbscriptName",WScript.ScriptFullName)
'Create_Shortcut Array("AllUsersStartup","MyvbscriptName",WScript.ScriptFullName)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' You actual code goes here
Msgbox "If UAC is enabled on the computer, something like this should work",vbinformation+vbSystemModal,Title
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Create_Shortcut(rArgs) 
    Dim objShell,objShortCut,ObjShortcutPath,ShortcutName,ShortcutPath,ShortcutLocation
    Dim TargetPath,Arguments,IconLocation,Description,HotKey
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If UBound(rArgs) > 1 Then
        ShortcutLocation       = cstr(rArgs(0))
        ShortcutPath           = objShell.SpecialFolders(ShortcutLocation)
        ShortcutName           = cstr(rArgs(1))
        Set objShortCut        = objShell.CreateShortcut(ShortcutPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
        TargetPath             = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(rArgs(2))
        objShortCut.TargetPath = TargetPath 
        If ShortcutPath = "" Then 
            MsgBox "Error The Shortcut Path Does Not Exsists On Your System."_
            ,vbCritical+vbSystemModal,Title
            wscript.quit(1)
        End If
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 2 Then
        Arguments = cstr(rArgs(3))
        objShortCut.Arguments = Arguments
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 3 Then
        IconLocation = cstr(rArgs(4))
        ObjShortCut.IconLocation = IconLocation
    End If

    If UBound(rArgs) > 4 Then
        Description = cstr(rArgs(5))
        ObjShortCut.Description = Description
    End If
    
    If UBound(rArgs) > 5 Then
        HotKey = cstr(rArgs(6))
        ObjShortCut.HotKey = HotKey
    End If
    objShortCut.Save
    On Error Resume Next
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ShowError() 
    Else 
        'objShell.Popup "The Shortcut "& chr(34) & ShortcutName & chr(34) &" is created Successfully !"& vbcrlf &_
        '"On " & chr(34) & ShortcutPath & chr(34),5,Title,vbInformation+vbSystemModal
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub ShowError()
    ErrDetail = "Description : " & Err.Description & vbCrlf & _
    "Error number : " & Err.Number & vbCrlf & _
    "Error source : " & Err.Source
    MsgBox ErrDetail,vbCritical+vbSystemModal,Title
    Err.clear
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub RunAsAdmin()
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
        , chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & chr(34) & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As far as I know, this will run the script as the current user, not with admin privileges

Comment: `Shell:Startup` is for the current user; but `shell:Common Startup` is for all users and needs admins priveliges !

Comment: No, you do need admin privileges to put something in that folder. But whatever is there will run as the current user

Comment: May be i didn't understand very well the OP Request ? he tells that his vbscript needs an action that will be run as admin rights ? in this case i suggest to add a function to run his vbscript with admin rights and create a shortcut in this folder !

Comment: @Berend Check my last edit !

Comment: That may work, I haven't tried. I suspect it will ask the user for the admin password, correct (i.e. the same as going into the advanced properties of a shortcut, and checking 'Run as admin')? The question doesn't really say if that's okay or not.

Comment: @Hackoo as I wrote in the question, "VBS file should be run automatically" that is without any actions from the user. Under "requires admin privs" I meant that VBS file should edit some system registry entry which can be edited only with admin privs. If I try to edit it manually at the account of standard user I get the "Error writing the value's new contents"

Comment: @sprsr can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1734796/edit) and add the contents of your vbscript to make some tests on my side, because the second vbscript should work with admin rights.